# eliminate ALL motion damping in hard body physics

Tags: scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

When I create a simulation of a hard ball rolling in a hard bowl,  the ball eventually loses energy, slows down, and stops.  Think of the bowl as curved spacetime and the ball as ... a ball.  :)

Since the simulated ball will be in a hard vacuum there should be nothing to slow it down.   Thus I want the ball to continue to roll with the same energy until I stick something else in the way.

I have tried turning off all damping for the bowl and the ball, friction to zero,  bounciness to zero, and rotation to zero and it still slows down.

I have been thinking of using scripting to add a slight boost to the velocity every few frames,   but I am hoping that there is an easier way.   Any suggestions?

TIA
Danl

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file since we cannot know any of your settings or what you have done. thx.

Comment: How do I provide the blend file?  I don't see any options for "attach file", etc,,,

Comment: See [this post](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3051/53447)

Comment: Here is the blend file.  It's really basic.  I ran the animation out to 500 so that you can see that the ball's oscilations are slowly being damped.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=jpR26APx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/jpR26APx/)

Comment: (Small advice: calculating physics on high density meshes can significantly slow down the baking. Prefer using lighter meshes and add a subdivision modifier on top of it. You will save yourself a lot of time baking. You don't need a sphere made of 16 128 triangles, 256 with lvl2 subdiv would perform way faster and have enough precision for what Blender's physics engine can do.)

Comment: @L0Lock -  Is there a good place to read about the actual functioning of the Blender physics engine?   For example,  I assume it's solving a series of differential eq's using something like a Runga Kutta algorithm?   If an object is impacting on a surface,  does it use the normal of the mesh FACE,  or does it calculate the normal from several faces, edges, or  ... does it use magic ???   :)

Meanwhile,  did you see how the ball slows down?    What mistake have I made?

Comment: Blender uses the Bullet engine afaik, you can check its documentation, but I don't think Blender exposes all the possible settings of Bullet so you are limited by Blender's implementation.